# Reduce lambda prints from bottom to top

Tags: python, lambda

I wanted to try to implement reduce lambda to print from a file.

```
reduce((lambda x,y: y + x), iterLines, "")
```

The text file looks like this

```
Starting a new phase
Phase 1 completed
Preparing phase 2
Phase 2 loading
Interruption detected
Incomplete!
```

The code I have is this (it is reading a file and then finding a string, and if that string is found, it will print that line as well as 2 above it)

```
iterLines = []
with open('file.txt') as text_file:
    N = 2
    lines = text_file.read().splitlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if "Incomplete!" in line:
            j = i-N if i>N else 0
            for k in range(j,i+1):
                 iterLines.append(lines[k].strip())

# iterLines = '\n'.join(iterLines)
for elem in iterLines:
    print(elem)
print(iterLines) #this works

reduce((lambda x,y: y + x), iterLines, "")
```

The output of print(iterLines) is as follows:

```
Phase 2 loading
Interruption detected
Incomplete!
```

However, when I use the reduce lambda, the output is the opposite

```
Incomplete!
Interruption detected
Phase 2 loading
```

Any reason as to why the lines are being swapped?

Comment: What on Earth is `f{y}` supposed to be doing?

Comment: @ShadowRanger y is the current item in iteration. See: https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functools.html#functools.reduce

Comment: @pygeek: I'm aware of how `reduce` works. But `f{y}` isn't valid Python syntax for anything. Plain `y + x` would make sense (but produce the reversed output they don't want), but `f{y} + x` is a `SyntaxError`. Either plain `y` or maybe `f'{y}'` would make sense (though given the items are already strings, `f'{y}'` would be pointless).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I have been trying to learn python the past 2-3 months. The reason that is there is a f{y} is because it is part of a larger code-where I am making my output into a friendly website in html. At the end, I am trying to make a handy python reference page for myself. 
in my python code, i have this

`html_content = f"""` where I end up inputting `{reduce((lambda x,y: f"<p>{x}</p>" + y), iterLines, "")}
But yes, I forgot to remove "f{}" portion when asking this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're appending the previous result to the current item, but desire the reverse:

`reduce((lambda x,y: y + x), iterLines, "")`

Instead, append `y` to `x`:

`reduce((lambda x,y: x + y), iterLines, "")`